# Eating specific exceptions in Python while using standard exception types

Tags: python, exception

Background: I'm somewhat new to Python, and I'm writing a small roguelike with TDL while taking a course on Python. I'm attempting to make things "pythonic" (my background is mostly in C#).

According to my courseware, there are three things that are "pythonic":

- Throw standard exception types unless you really need something different
- Don't check pre-conditions extensively; use `try`/`except` and recover appropriately
- Use duck-typing. Don't check if methods exist, just call them.

In the main loop of my game, I have a collection of `entities`. I iterate over them and, if they're walkable, call `walk`. My code looks something like this:

```
for e in self.area_map.entities:
    try:
        e.walk()
    except AttributeError:
        # not walkable
        pass
    except ValueError:
        # all adjacent tiles are not walkable
        pass
```

I recently introduced a bug where one of my entities referenced a variable that ended up being `None` instead of having a value. Instead of catching this error, I ended up with my entities simply not walking.

It turns out that my two exceptions that I catch can include a wide variety of different exceptions; however, I don't want to hide them -- I only want to hide specific cases (one where the method doesn't exist, and one where my code throws a `ValueError`).

What's the right way of doing this?

Currently, I'm checking if the exception message is something specific, which smells to me (what if a newer version of Python tweaks the exception message slightly?)

My code now looks like this:

```
    for entity in self.area_map.entities:
        try:
            entity.walk()
        except AttributeError as a:
            # AttributeError => entity isn't walkable.                
            message = str(a)
            if not "object has no attribute 'walk'" in message:
                raise
        except ValueError as v:
            # ValueError => nothing adjacent to walk to.
            message = str(v)
            if message is not "There are no available adjacent locations":
                raise
```

What's the right way to do this?